# sp² hybridized orbital

Tags: electronic-configuration, orbitals, hybridization

I do not understand why and how an atom with $\ce{sp^2}$ hybridization has only one p orbital??

For example in pyridine why is the lone pair of nitrogen not counted as a pi electron.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The picture below from the [UC Davis ChemWiki](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Organic_Chemistry/Organic_Chemistry_With_a_Biological_Emphasis/Chapter_07%3A_Organic_compounds_as_acids_and_bases/Section_7.4%3A_More_on_resonance_effects_on_acidity_and_basicity#7.4B:_The_basicity_of_nitrogen-containing_groups:_aniline.2C_imines.2C_pyridine.2C_and_pyrrole) summarizes why that lone pair is not available. It also explains how pyridine can function as a base.
[image: pyridine orbitals]

The lone pair in the $sp^2$ orbital is perpendicular to the $p$ orbitals and $\pi$ bonds in the molecule. the electron pair from the nitrogen that participates in aromaticity is **the one in the $\ce{C=N}$ bond**.

To answer your first question about hybridization, we have a conservation law that guarantees that when orbitals mix (for any reason), we need to get the same number of orbitals out as we put in. The law is the [Conservation of Angular Momentum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum#Conservation_of_angular_momentum), which does apply in quantum systems.

Nitrogen, in its valence shell, has four orbitals: $2s,2p_x,2p_y,2p_z$. The $sp^2$ hybridization is achieved by mixing two $p$ orbitals and one $s$ orbital. Because of the conversation of angular momentum, four orbitals in means four orbitals out. Thus, the $p$ orbital that was not mixed is still there (and is the only one still there).

$$[s,p,p],p\implies[sp^2,sp^,sp^2],p$$

We cannot have two $p$ orbitals at an $sp^2$ hybridized atom because then we would have 5 orbitals (or we would not have $sp^2$).

> Now, let's create a general rule for aromatic heterocycles.

Look at pyrrole (also from ChemWiki);

[image: pyrrole]

In the structure of pyrrole, the $\ce{N-H}$ bond uses the $sp^2$ orbital and the lone pair is in the $p$ orbital. In general, if there is a double bond drawn to the nitrogen atom (like in pyridine), then the $\pi$ bond uses the $p$ orbital and the lone pair is in the $sp^2$ orbital and does not count toward aromaticity. If there is no double bond drawn to the nitrogen atom, usually there is a $\ce{N-H}$ bond (or some other bond to the nitrogen). This $\ce{N-H}$ bond uses the $sp^2$ orbital and the lone pair uses the $p$ orbital and counts toward aromaticity.

Comment: Good answer.But I have a doubt.If an acid is added to pyridine,will the aromaticity be preserved or destroyed as in case of pyrrole ?

Comment: Pyridine remains aromatic when protonated. The lone pair that enables pyridine to be a base is orthogonal to the pi system.

Comment: Actually pyrrole gets C-protonated IIRC

Comment: @Mithoron - it likely does, but either way, aromaticity is lost.