# Why is the lone pair of pyridine's nitrogen atom not part of the aromatic ring?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, hybridization, heterocyclic-compounds

In pyrrole, the lone pair of electrons belonging to the nitrogen is part of the aromatic ring. However, in pyridine it is part of an sp2-hybridized orbital. Why can't it be in the p-orbital and take part in the aromatic ring?

I mean, why can't the lone pair in pyrrole be in the p-orbital, with the sp2-hybridized orbital (which is not bonded to anything) sporting a single electron?

I'm not talking about the nitrogen atom having two p-orbitals participating in the aromatic ring. That would be strange. I wonder why the existing p-orbital of N cannot carry two electrons, the way it does in pyrrole.

[image]

---

P.S. A related question, with a very interesting answer: [sp2-hybpidization in pyridine and pyrrole](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/27309/sp%C2%B2-hybridized-orbital)

Comment: Because there is **already** a $p$ orbital of nitrogen which takes part in the aromatic ring. You can't have two $p$ orbitals on one atom pointing in the same direction. And you can't have orbital take part in the ring if it is oriented differently.

Comment: Huckel's rule demands that there be 4n+2 pi electrons in the ring. Each carbon contributes one, making for a total of 5 from the carbons. If your nitrogen lone pair is in the ring, then you will have seven pi electrons. $7 \neq 4n +2$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @orthocresol - so it's solely to satisfy Huckel's rule? And the same applies to pyrrole - it cannot stick out the lone pair, because that way the aromatic ring will be disrupted, so it has to use the lone pair in the aromatic ring?

Comment: If your lone pair is pointing upwards, where would be your _existing_ p orbital on N? That's my point, and it comes before counting electrons for Huckel.

Comment: @IvanNeretin - I worded my question badly in the beginning. My whole point was, why can't the lone pair be instead in that p-orbital poining upwards - instead of its real position, which is i the sp2-orbital.

Comment: Yes, the fact that you put one electron in the p orbital and two in the sp2 orbital is solely to satisfy Huckel's rule. For pyrrole, there are only four other carbons which contribute one electron each, and the nitrogen therefore has to give two of its own in order for it to reach $4n+2$. If the lone pair sticks out, the aromatic ring would not be "disrupted". The ring would just not be aromatic. Also, the sp2 orbital in pyrrole is bonded to a hydrogen 1s.

Comment: Well, then it's Huckel's rule alright. Also, if you'd have a pair on $p$, you'd have an unpaired electron on that $sp^2$, which is not nice.

Comment: Might find useful? http://www.chem.ucla.edu/~harding/tutorials/lone_pair.pdf

Comment: @orthocresol can you please explain this question to me ? The OP asks why can't the lone pair in pyrrole be in the p orbital.... But it already is! The lone pair is in the p orbital taking part in resonance.

Comment: @Ali I don't know what you're saying. The question is clearly about pyridine.

Comment: @orthocresol In the description, the OP says "I mean, why can't the lone pair in pyrrole be in the p-orbital, with the sp2-hybridized orbital (which is not bonded to anything) sporting a single electron"

Comment: @Ali I assume that's a typo and that the OP meant pyridine. It fits in with the general question.

Comment: @orthocresol I thought moderators can edit a question? Also ,no one bothered to correct a question having 12 upvotes ? So people don't actually read the description and just answer with whatever general view they have about the question ?

Comment: @Ali Anybody can edit a question, including you and I. I don't really understand why you're asking me about this, or what you hope to accomplish by this, because I can't control how other people behave on this website. How am I supposed to tell you what runs through the minds of every user here and why they didn't edit it or whether they read it or not?

Comment: @orthocresol I am asking you about this because -1. Because you are a moderator. I thought moderators had special edit privileges . My edits would be peer reviewed , yours wouldn't be. 2. Because you were involved with the question a long time ago 3. Because I was surprised that a question with so many upvotes has an error , although a trivial one and nobody pointed it out even in the comment section. That is unlike stackexchange. Major reason is point 3 ,not because I wanted to argue over some typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As follows from our discussion in the comments to the question, pyridine uses only a single electron in the p-orbital in order to comply with [Huckel's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%BCckel%27s_rule). Kudos to [Orthocresol](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/50266/why-is-the-lone-pair-of-pyridines-nitrogen-atom-not-part-of-the-aromatic-ring#comment84668_50266):

> Huckel's rule demands that there be 4n+2 pi electrons in the ring. Each carbon contributes one, making for a total of 5 from the carbons. If your nitrogen lone pair is in the ring, then you will have seven pi electrons. $7≠4n+27≠4n+2$ for $n ∈Z$

Of course, electrons know nothing of Huckel and his rule, but apparently they position themselves into the most energetically suitable configuration. I am not yet qualified to explain why exactly it is the most suitable one.

Comment: The key point is mentioned here! Electrons position themselves in the most suitable configuration, and if you look at the MO Diagram of Pyridine it becomes clear why the line pair will sit in Nitrogen rather than in the p Orbital

Comment: @ITTsoi - that may well be so, and I've been shown an MO diagram in the chat, but I haven't yet mastered the MO theory. If I do that, I'll expand my answer. Or maybe someone else will post an additional answer with an MO-based explanation.

Comment: Huckels rule is irrelevant and the orbitals are not "single" electrons.

Answer (score 4):

**It has the wrong geometry**

The other P orbital can't participate in the aromatic ring because it has the wrong geometry: it points in a direction orthogonal to the orbitals involved in the aromatic part of the ring. The picture in the question shows this clearly.

There is already a P-orbital on nitrogen involved in the aromatic system of the ring (the one that points "up"). The orbital coloured yellow-ish in the picture doesn't overlap with the aromatic system at all as it points "out" from the ring and (if you did calculations) would have no overlap with the other orbitals in the the aromatic system. No overlap means it can't be involved in aromaticity. It is, ultimately, simple geometry and no other explanations are required.